# Access 2007 to SQL Server Secure Connection

Tags: sql-server, security, ms-access-2007

Is it possible to get Access 2007 to link to SQLServer via a secure connection so local area network traffic is encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself but it looks like you can use ssl encryption on network traffic through odbc:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898/en-us

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising.  I will let you know how I get on